# MacPorts doesn't install Python module in right place for virtualenv

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv, macports

I can't seem to find the exact situation I have, please point me to a duplicate if there is one.

I am using virtualenv and python and trying to install a module but no matter which version of python 'which python' comes up with MacPorts seems to install the modules in the default macports python location (/opt/local/share) for the default macports python (/opt/local/bin).

When the virtualenv is activated, 'which python' gives a python version in ~/Documents/.../bin/python (It is a python version 2.7.3), which is correct.

If virtualenv not activated, I have tried either switching to either the system python version (Apple default installed version) or the default macports one which is /opt/local/bin (which is also a 2.7.3 version).

After installation, in the python interpreter I can successfully import my module when the virtualenv is not activated, but python can't find the module when virtualenv is activated.

I can't use pip or easy_install to install this module (PyQt4) b/c there is known bug where they error.

How can I get macports to install in the proper location for my virtualenv ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macports only installs python modules in the site-packages directory directly corresponding to the python interpreter. It does this to allow multiple different interpreters to be installed.

Macports is also installed under the root user and not your own account. It can't therefore know about virtualenv setups which are controlled by settings in your user environment.

what you have to do is install the complex modules e.g. PyQT4 and virtualenv and then create your virtualenv from that ie using `--system-site-packages`